# Make graphviz arrow tails and heads to start and terminate at exact points

Tags: graphviz

I have this code.

```
digraph arrowtailhead {
    graph [rankdir="LR", splines=ortho];
    node [shape=record];

    l1 [label="A\l|b\l"];
    l2 [label="C\l|d\l"];
    l3 [label="E\l|f\l"];
    l4 [label="G\l|h\l"];
    l5 [label="I\l|j\l"];
    l6 [label="K\l|l\l"];

    l1 -> l2 -> l6;
    l1 -> l3;
    l1 -> l4;
    l1 -> l5;
}
```

[image]

As you see, the arrow start and termination points are rather random.
I want all the arrows to start and terminate at the horizontal center lines, just like the one from C to K.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Orthogonal edges in graphviz do not support ports](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2142), therefore it is not possible to define the exact start and termination point of those edges.